# Heroku Deploy error: 'sh: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution' and undefined local variable or method `install_language_pack_gems'

Tags: heroku, deployment

Heroku Deploy for Rails app is failing currently. I am getting the following error message. I haven't changed any gems or rails code but just changed some static HTML and CSS files.

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
       Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
       Old: ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
       New: ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]
sh: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
sh: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
/app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:760:in `block in purge_bundler_cache': undefined local variable or method `install_language_pack_gems' for #<LanguagePack::Rails4:0x00000001974ab8> (NameError)
```

Comment: Yep, same here. Heroku, come on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Heroku's fault. Perhaps just some caching issue, but maybe they just broke something. Anyway, the solution is to set the `BUILDPACK_URL` for your app to point to the latest Ruby Heroku buildpack:

`heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby -a <app-name>`

Comment: This shouldn't be needed anymore, we fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from the command line. I think you're upgrading versions and somehow aren't pointing to the correct buildpack.

```
heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack
```

More info here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks